# Using sipp variable inside <exec> section

Tags: sipp

How to inject a string from SIPP command line into `<exec>` section of script ?

SIPP wiki talks about declaration but not how to use it inside `<exec>`

**CMD:**

```
    sipp -sf sipp_pcap.txt ........ -key k1 "5060" -set pcap_file "abc.pcap"
```

**sipp_pcap.txt**

```
    <scenario name=" UAC">
    <Global variables="pcap_file" />
    <Reference variables="pcap_file" />

    ………..
    ……….


                     <exec play_pcap_video="/root/backup/[$pcap_file]” />

    …………..
    ……………..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue with sipp v.3.3 and in sipp v.3.5 its working, if you use `key` instead of `set` like below:

**CMD:**

```
    sipp -sf sipp_pcap.txt ........ -key k1 "5060" -key pcap_file "abc.pcap"
```

**sipp_pcap.txt**

```
    <scenario name=" UAC">
    <Global variables="pcap_file" />
    <Reference variables="pcap_file" />

    ………..
    ……….

                     // no $ symbol
                     <exec play_pcap_video="/root/backup/[pcap_file]” />

    …………..
    ……………..
```

PS: Still do not know how to use with `set`

Comment: Did you use official SIPp release? I'm asking because I'm unable to reproduce your solution, but there PR that hasn't been merged but does something very similar (https://github.com/SIPp/sipp/pull/330).